# RankNTypes and Church numerals

Tags: haskell, types, type-theory, higher-rank-types

I'm trying to study church numerals in Haskell by giving the numbers a type like this, with the idea that a natural number `n` is basically the expression that applies the function in the following type to the value of type `t` for `n` times.

```
type Nat = forall t. (t -> t) -> t -> t
```

With that idea, I can define `zero`, `successor`, `plus`, `mult` in the following ways:

```
zero :: Nat
zero = \f t -> t

succ :: Nat -> Nat
succ n = \f -> f . (n f)

plus :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
plus m n = \f -> (m f) . (n f)

mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult m n = \f -> m (n f) -- Equal to \f -> (m . n) f

-- Pointfree version
mult' :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult' = (.)
```

When I try to define exponentiation, I'd like to try applying the same reasoning that allowed me to define multiplication, namely **applying `mult m` `n` times to `1`**.

This leads to the following code

```
exp' :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
exp' m n = n (mult m) (succ zero)
```

But this does type check with the following error from GHC:

```
  Couldn't match type ‘t’ with ‘t1’
  ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      exp' :: forall t. Nat -> Nat -> (t -> t) -> t -> t
    at church.lhs:44:3
  ‘t1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a type expected by the context:
      forall t1. (t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1
    at church.lhs:44:17
  Expected type: ((t -> t) -> t -> t) -> (t -> t) -> t -> t
    Actual type: Nat -> Nat
```

The error seems to say that the typechecker is not instantiating the type for `n` properly, ideally type `t` should be instantiated with another (`t -> t`) for the expression to go through.

What's also confusing me is that the following code typechecks:

```
exp :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
exp m n = n ((.) m) (succ zero) -- replace mult by (.)
```

Would someone mind explaining what's the problem here? Why does the first definition of `exp'` not typecheck but the second `exp` typecheks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't work is it involves several impredicative instantiations, which isn't even normally allowed in Haskell. If you turn on `-XImpredicativeTypes`, you can get it to compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-} 

...

exp' :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
exp' m n = n (mult m) (succ zero)
```

The second version typechecks because `mult'` has a higher rank type, even though it is definitionally equal to `(.)`, so typechecking proceeds differently. Since the type of `(.)` is simpler (rank 1) typechecking will succeed more often.

The GHC docs warn `ImpredicativeTypes` does not work so I would caution against using it. The typical way to get around this it to simple use a `newtype`:

```
newtype Nat' = N { instN :: Nat } 

exp'' :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
exp'' m n = instN $ n (\(N q) -> N $ mult m q) (N $ succC zero)
```

---

To see the impredicative instantiation in action, you can use typed holes:

```
exp' :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
exp' m n = _ (mult m) (succC zero)
```

This will report the type `forall a . (Nat -> Nat) -> Nat -> (a -> a) -> a -> a`, which is the same as `(Nat -> Nat) -> Nat -> Nat`. Since you place `n` there, you have to unify this type with `forall a . (a -> a) -> a -> a`, which involves instantiating the type variable `a` with the polytype `Nat`.